# Auto-Indent of the list environment in the Editor of TeXworks

Tags: lists, indentation, texworks

Does above mode exist in Texworks? I Tried `Format-->Auto-Indent Mode` dropdown in the Toolbar but none of the options worked to indent my following nested list example:

Sometimes, if I copy a list from another source where it was not properly indented, and paste it to TeXworks it still remains improperly indented as in the following example:

[image]

In TeXworks, I would like it to be automatically indented properly by clicking some button or something (like we do for xml/html in some xml/html editors) and look something similar to the following:

[image]

`TeXworks version`: 0.6.1 May 01, 2016

`TeXworks obtained from`: MikTeX

`Operating system`: Windows 10

**NOTE**: The question is related to Editor (left pane) of TeXworks and **not** about the display - in the right pane - of the typeset.

Comment: Did you try selecting the list before applying the option?

Comment: @cfr Yes. And nothing happened.